# Trying to plot two variable function, calculating function loop gives wrong shape

Tags: python, loops, matplotlib, contour

I have some function `f`, which is some compliciated integral taking two parameters `x` and `y` . I want to make contour plot in this parameter space (i.e. over some arrays `X` and `Y`), so I use loops over those two paremeters.
My code looks like this:

```
def Z_values(X,Y,f):
  matrix=[]
  columns=[]
  for x in X:
    for y in Y:
       a=f(x,y)
       columns.append(a)
    matrix.append(columns)
    columns.clear()
return matrix

plt.contour(X,Y,Z_values(X,Y,f))
plt.show()
```

I get following error:
`TypeError: Input z must be at least a (2, 2) shaped array, but has shape (4, 0))`
I don't understand what I do wrong in the loop. What is wrong?

Edit: wrong copypasted error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot create `columns` outside the loop and clear it in the loop. In such case the `matrix` actually contains the reference points to the same `column` and it's getting cleared again and again. So the function `Z_values` returns list of empty list.

Corrected code as below:

```py
def Z_values(X,Y,f):
    matrix=[]
    for x in X:
        columns=[]
        for y in Y:
            a=f(x,y)
            columns.append(a)
        matrix.append(columns)
    return matrix

plt.contour(X,Y,Z_values(X,Y,lambda x,y: np.exp(x**2+y**2)))
plt.show()
```

I would suggest you to learn some basic C/C++ programming to understand the concept of reference/pointer and how they are related to memory addresses where the data are actually stored. This will help you avoid this kind of mistake.